# jquery validation html element border color change issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

We are using jquery validation plugin to validate the form elements.
(http://jqueryvalidation.org/)
We are able to see the error messages when the input goes wrong.
Also we are setting the html component border to red while this error(by default given by the plugin).
The color change is not working for bootstrap text boxes . Any idea on this?

HTML :

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="IpTableDiv">
            <form name="MyForm" id="MyForm" method="post">
                <table class="table table-bordered form-grid">
                    <thead>
                    <tr class="btitle">
                        <th width="25%">Settings</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info">IP Address</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="ipAddress" name="ip_IP_ADDR" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$.validator.addMethod('validIPAddress', function (value, element, param) {
    var isValid = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/.test(value);
    return isValid;
});


$("#MyForm").validate({
    rules: {
        ip_IP_ADDR: {
            required: true,
            validIPAddress: true
        },
    },
    messages: {
        ip_IP_ADDR: {
            validIPAddress: "Please enter a valid IP Address"
        },
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).closest('.form-control').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).closest(".form-control").removeClass("has-error");
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: There may be a conflict between styles, have you tried enforcing your style using the `!important` keyword, for example `border: solid 1px red !important;`

Comment: yes . i tried this Martin . No use .

Comment: Did you tried: `$(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');` ?

Comment: Will tryb that and update .

Comment: Are you sure you have all your CSS and jQuery files in the right order? It seems to work for me. https://jsfiddle.net/jrek8mkf/

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using the `.form-group` class so that wouldn't change anything and you should post your CSS since that's what the question is ultimately about:  `.has-error.form-control,
.has-error.form-control:focus {
  border-color: red;
}`

Comment: When i use form-group it is not working.When i use form-control , the border color is changed for all the other elements in this form.